# Import data from Excel into SQL Server using queries

Tags: sql-server, excel

If I am not allowed to use the import function of SQL Server to bring data from Excel into SQL Server, would you be able to use queries to import the data?

Comment: Of course you can import. But please do more research and show something you have already done so that people can help you solve your issue. 
This page has everything you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Even without the import function/wizard, you can still, as a last resort, create a function on Excel to write down an  (or many) `INSERT` statement

Comment: Easiest way: import the excel file to your local SQL server then insert into target server with linked server

Comment: If you can't (for some reason) use the import function, you'll need to *push* the data rather than pull (as not being about to use Import **strongly** suggests you can't put files in a location the that SQL Server's service account can access). you could, therefore use VBA or something to import the data, or write a .net application to read the file and `INSERT` it to the database.

Comment: Is this for a one-time task or for recurring process?

Comment: You can actually create a formula in Excel that packages each of the rows into an insert statement, then copy-paste into a query window and run the script. It is a very low-tech but also low-complexity option.

Comment: have you tried to use BULK INSERT ??  https://codingsight.com/sql-server-bulk-insert-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to export data from Excel to SQL Server.  Here is one concept.

```
Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=server_name"
'cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=Yes"


'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = '2013-01-22' WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL


'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```